# Password protected phone dont allow opening database when it is locked

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

In phonegap app I have some background database operation running when phone is put in background everything seems to be working fine when phone is not protected by password but once phone is password protected I am getting following Error

```
DOM Exception 18
```

On line where I am opening database

```
var loDBObj = window.openDatabase(loUserSettings.ServerUserDBName, "1.0", "User DataBase " + loUserSettings.ServerId + "_" + CurrentUserId(), 200000);
```

I have tried adding before opening database

```
navigator.openDatabase = window.openDatabase = DroidDB_openDatabase;
window.droiddb = new DroidDB();
```

And also I have tried whitelist plugin with

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible as i have gone through some forums. As apple don't allow any file operation after the phone is locked. You can try running Music or anything in background which will keep active your service on local storage but however apple will reject it if any services you grant access is not properly or legally used.

You can take example of any big application like whats app they even send only notification and don't store messages when your phone is password protected.